# Unexpected behaviour of Api gateway as trigger of AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

We are using AWS lambda service and our lambda is a monolith service which serves the below requests.

1. GET /User
2. POST /User
3. Delete /User

We have added a trigger with HTTP method as **ANY** to the lambda which works fine but we also have an endpoint which can return all the users for audit purposes.

1. GET /Users

We can use multiple triggers for AWS lambda. I added this as a separate trigger on my existing lambda which gives unexpected errors. Sometimes, the API works for some hits but throws access denied for other hits. The behaviour is the same for another API too.

I know it's not a good practice to have two GET endpoints but does anyone have any experience around it? IMO, both the APIs should work as it just defines the permissions on lambda.

We tried combining the trigger using regex but it does not expect it as part of ARN.